# Should I use an exception or not?

Tags: java, exception, if-statement

What I'm doing here is a simple login. What I'm not sure about is if I should use an exception to signal that the login was unsuccessfull (wrong nickname or wrong password or both) or just a simple if\else construct.

```
try
{
     catalogo.getUtenteAttivo();
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(login, "Login avvenuto con successo", "Avviso", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
catch(InvalidLoginException exception)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(login, "Login non riuscito", "Errore", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

The code is in italian, but you can get a general idea of what I was trying to do.

Comment: I'd rather not: unsuccessful login is not an exceptional, but ordinal event; so it's more netural to return boolean: true on success and false otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simple if/else should be fine.  An `Exception` is for some usually wrong, exceptional event that occurs within the context of your code.  A failed login is much more like a business event.  It is expected, and your code would be working properly.

I would have whatever method this is to check a user's credentials return the proper status than to throw an exception if the login fails.

However, if the process that checks the login fails itself, then that is an exception condition and *that* should throw an exception.

Comment: Though I generally agree, without knowing what getUtenteAttivo() actually does, it's hard to say if a failed login can be "exceptional" or not.  If so, throwing a **Checked** Exception would be appropriate.  If not, you are correct and a simple true/false is o.k.

Comment: I'll remove the exception as you suggested, especially considering the fact that the database is created on the go in the Starter class so there really isn't something exceptional waiting around the corner.

Answer (score 2):

The conventional wisdom is to **Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions** (See Effective Java, Joshua Bloch.

I would use regular control flow for this case, which is part of the regular execution of the program. Save exceptions for the more unusual circumstances, such as not being able to connect with the database.

Nevertheless, using an exception here is not crazy, just not my choice.

Answer (score 1):

I think an Exception is appropriate here.  In the long run, `getUtenteAttivo()` is likely to check with a database, across to a network server, etc. and throw some sort of Exception.  (The Java security/password libraries throw all kinds of exceptions)  Note: in that case, also check for IOExceptions etc...

Normally, you might avoid Exceptions for performance reasons, but that's not an issue here.

Another reason to throw is to make sure the client actually catches them and doesn't forget to check the true/false.  In this case that is important.

Answer (score 0):

For such a mundane situation, i'd say it does not really matter ;-) but you must realize that throwing an exception is an expensive operation and that nobody should use exceptions to pass values. So if checking if a password matches or not is trivial, you may want to just return a boolean and save your exceptions for times where something went wrong, such as a db or ldap server down.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree with you now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A common pattern is to provide both a "Try" and a "Do" method--in this case, a `TryLogin` method which will indicate whether a login succeeded or not, and a `Login` method which will return if the login succeeds and throw an exception if it fails.  If both methods are available, code which is prepared to do something sensible in case a login fails for expected reasons need not deal with exceptions, but code which can't do anything useful if the login fails can simply let the exception "bubble up".  An alternative approach which isn't usable in all cases but might be suitable here would be to have `Login` return unconditionally, but have an `AssertLoggedIn` method which could be called by code which couldn't do anything useful if the login failed.  Following the login attempt with `AssertLoggedIn` would give the connection class a chance to throw an exception in case the login failed, possibly including some (hopefully non-security-sensitive) information that might help diagnose the problem.